# LIMIT condition not working as expected

Tags: mysql, limit

SELECTing rows with LIMIT condition delivers unexpected number of rows:

```
SELECT `id`, `Date`, `row1`, `row2`, `row3`, `row4`, `row5` 
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY `id` ASC, `Date` ASC 
LIMIT 1, 800
```

This SELECT shows exactly what it should: 800 rows

```
SELECT `id`, `Date`, `row1`, `row2`, `row3`, `row4`, `row5` 
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY `id` ASC, `Date` ASC 
LIMIT 801, 1600
```

This SELECT does ***not*** deliver what it should: delivering 1600 rows instead of 800.

Why is LIMIT condition not working properly?

Comment: Why would you have a column called row? You like confusion?

Comment: You are [asking for `1600` rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), you get `1600` rows.

Comment: 800 minus 1 is 799. So the fact that you get 800 rows is obviously an indication that LIMIT returns the quantity of rows specified in the LIMIT (if available), and not the number of rows specified in the limit minus the number of rows specified in the offset. You've perfectly illustrated this fact for yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIMIT and Offset are not from and to values. Offset is the number of documents/rows to skip and limit is the maximum number of rows to be shown. In your case, to skip 800 rows and show next 800 records, it should be LIMIT 800,800

Answer (score 0):

limit and offset are reversed when you use comma syntax, so it's:

LIMIT offset, limit

which is equivalent to:

LIMIT limit OFFSET offset